# SED returning error 2 when launched by Wpkg

Tags: windows, regex, windows-command-prompt, sed

## Case

I am deploying a software product using [Wpkg](http://wpkg.org/) over Windows workstations. I need to disable product's faulty automatic update and the best solution in this case is to modify one configuration file with a following regular expression: `s/<value>.*<\/value>/<value>file:\\\\<\/value>/g`

## Problem

To perform the described task, I use SED:

```
%BASH%\sed "s/<value>.*<\/value>/<value>file:\\\\<\/value>/g" "MyApp.config" > "MyApp.config.tmp"`
```

Whenever I do it from commandline, it works.

But once I paste it into Wpkg (`<>` escaped due to `XML` constraints):

```
<install cmd='%BASH%\sed "s/&lt;value&gt;.*&lt;\/value&gt;/&lt;value&gt;file:\\\\&lt;\/value&gt;/g" "%PKG_DESTINATION%\MyApp.config" &gt; "%PKG_DESTINATION%\MyApp.config.tmp"' />
```

...it fails, creating no new files and... returning mysterious error code 2:

```
Exit code returned non-successful value (2) on command '%BASH%\sed "s/<value>.*<
\/value>/<value>file:\\\\<\/value>/g" "%PKG_DESTINATION%\MyApp.config" > "%PKG_D
ESTINATION%\MyApp.config.tmp"'.
```

## Question

After a pointless hour and half of searching for that mysterious error code 2 I begin to believe that there is either something wrong in me vs. Google relationship, or there really is no documentation for that error. [Official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) also left me blind.

I've tried to dump `stderr` of that Wpkg command to text file, but the file ain't being created, which suggests no `stderr` to dump.

Perhaps a second or third pair of eyes would help me find the source of the problem?

Comment: Could you indicate if this is still an issue? Have you considered to use PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the error 2 was returned not by the `sed` command, but by the Wpkg being unable to find the `%BASH%\sed.exe` file :)